# How to make changes on an excel column by changing another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, editing

So I want to have a column that when I make changes there, the changes are aplied to another column, and by changes I men even deleting columns, I tried using the =&A! formula but all goues down hill when I delete a row from the column

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You're going to have to be more specific. Please [edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/806827/edit) to include some sample data with a description of how you want the second column to update when changes are made to the first column.

Comment: A formula can not change contents in another cell and it cannot delete columns. Step back and describe the bigger picture.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple.

For example, you want to update the data in 1st column and it will be reflected in 2nd column.

1. Update the value in 1st column
2. Then just click on the second column (in place of B1)
3. Just type equalto (=) and select 1st element of 1st column (A1)
4. Drag the formula in the 2nd column

Now you will see, whatever you will update in the 1st column, it will be reflected on the 2nd column. When you will delete anything from 1st column, then it will show 0 (zero) in the corresponding row.